# How to check if the form field is enabled or disabled in AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs

In an AngularJS controller, how do I check if a particular field is enabled or disabled? I have looked to the documentation of AngularJS but I didn't found any form field property to indicate the enabled/disabled state of a field.

Comment: It is not good practice to manage dom elements from controllers.

Comment: I am not managing any dom element. I just want to know its state.

Comment: Where's the difference? The form is part of the view, the controller has nothing to do with the view. The link between them is the model. That is there should be a property in your model that controls the state of the form field.

Answer (score 3):

Angular's jqLite supports prop(). So if you check the .prop('disabled') it should return a boolean with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable on your controller and use it on your form:

controller:

```
$scope.fieldDisabled = true;

$scope.submitForm = function(){
    alert("Disabled: " + $scope.fieldDisabled);
}
```

view:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-disabled="fieldDisabled" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<button ng-click="fieldDisabled = !fieldDisabled">Toggle disable</button>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/skhuk171/)